# Django filter/exclude giving erroneous result, why?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django query that is giving me an erroneous queryset. From the following individual queries, it should give me 1 - 0 = 1, but instead it gives me 0 results. Why is this so?

```
>>> MessageThread.objects.filter(message__recipient=p2)
[<MessageThread: message thread one>]
>>> MessageThread.objects.filter(message__status='deleted', message__recipient=p2)
[]
>>> MessageThread.objects.filter(message__recipient=p2)
    .exclude(message__status='deleted', message__recipient=p2)
[]
```

How would I build a query to get query1 - query2? This is what I need in sql:

```
SELECT * FROM messaging_messagethread 
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT thread_id FROM messaging_message 
     WHERE status = 'deleted' AND recipient_id=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The lookups you put inside an exclude or filter arguments are ANDed when they parse to SQL statements. So, in your last query you are doing this (in English):

> Give me all the MessageThread objects that have a message with "p2" as recipient and from those objects, quit all messages that have "deleted" as status and "p2" as a recipient.

So basically, you are excluding what you filter. If you want to get all messages with "p2" as a recipient that aren't deleted, you can do this:

**EDIT** Ok, now i understand what you need. So you basically want just the exclude part of the query on your question. I think you need this:

```
MessageThread.objects.exclude(message__status='deleted', message__recipient_id=4)
```

Comment: Yup, so I tried this and it does not yield correct results, as it isn't restrictive enough, it will exclude messages that have been deleted by another user, but not the current user. The only way I could figure this out is with the following sql: `SELECT * FROM messaging_messagethread WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT thread_id FROM messaging_message WHERE status = 'deleted' AND recipient_id=4)`

Comment: I think there is a difference between the SQL you put in your question and what you said in your comment. What is the "recipient" field in your "message" model means? Because it doesn't seems to be the user that delete that message. Are you sure your SQL is what you need? If so, my answer should suit your need. Otherwise, try to add your models here and write in English what do you want to get from the query.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested (obviously since I don't have your project installed locally), but this should work:

```
exclude_ids = Message.objects.filter(
    status="deleted", recipient_id=4
    ).values_list("thread_id", flat=True)
MessageThread.objects.exclude(id__in=exclude_ids)
```

NB : I didn't add a `distinct` clause because it doesn't necessarily works well with ordering and I don't know wether you used ordering in your models.